# Why is the HTML from a website different from the HTML that Python's request library gives?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to familiarize myself with requests and BeautifulSoup so I gave myself a mini-project. I'm trying to make a program that displays the shoes on Footlocker's release calendar
(https://www.footlocker.com/release-dates/) like so:

- ShoeName#1     Date#1
- ShoeName#2     Date#2
- ShoeName#3     Date#3
- ShoeName#4     Date#4

So far I have this:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    url = "https://www.footlocker.com/release-dates/"
    resp = req.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
```

However when I load the HTML to parse with BeautifulSoup the HTML code with the information containing the dates and names of the shoes does not appear like it does when I use inspect element directly on the website. I assume this is because the HTML with the shoe's information is generated by Javascript. If so how can I load it with requests?

Thank you.

Comment: Learn and use `Selenium`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have selenium installed in your machine, that's okay otherwise, install it. Here is how you go.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.footlocker.com/release-dates/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
driver.quit()
for item in soup.select(".day"):
    shoe = item.select_one(".productName").get_text()
    date = item.select_one(".date").get_text()
    print(shoe,date)
```

Partial results:

```
Jordan Retro 1 HI OG 1Aug
Kids' Jordan Retro 1 HI OG 1Aug
Jordan Retro 1 HI OG 1Aug
Kids' Jordan Retro 1 HI OG 1Aug
Nike Kobe A.D. NXT 1Aug
Nike Dualtone Racer 1Aug
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't load it with `requests`, what you can and should use it to load is **[`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)** together with **[`ChromeDriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)**(or any other browser), once using it, you don't even need to use `bs4` for the parsing job:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.footlocker.com/release-dates/")

names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("productName")
names = [name.text for name in names]
days = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("days")
days = [day.text for day in days]
months = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("month")
months = [month.text for month in months]

dates = list(zip(days, months))
data = list(zip(names, dates))
```

Since all product's names are in `<div class="productImage"></div>` tags, it's easy to grab all of the elements with `.find_elements_by_class_name` and later on use *list comprehension* syntax to get all the desired element's texts. The same process is used to find all the dates and months texts.

Because all of them are ordered when parsed, using `zip` is a handy way to get them all together in only one big list of tuples. A demo of how the items in `data` looks like:

```
>>> data[:10]
[('Jordan Retro 1 HI OG', ('1', 'Aug')), ("Kids' Jordan Retro 1 HI OG", ('1', 'Aug')), ('Jordan Retro 1 HI OG', ('1', 'Aug')), ("Kids' Jordan Retro 1 HI OG", ('1', 'Aug')), ('Nike Kobe A.D. NXT', ('1', 'Aug')), ('Nike Dualtone Racer', ('1', 'Aug')), ('Nike Duelist Racer', ('1', 'Aug')), ('Jordan Super.Fly 2017', ('3', 'Aug')), ("Kids' Jordan Super.Fly 2017", ('3', 'Aug')), ('Nike Air VaporMax Flyknit', ('3', 'Aug'))]
```